# Android app dies when saving image captured with camera and rotating phone

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, jquery-mobile, android-camera

[EDIT]

I actually solved this adding the following line to my activity manifest:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

I'm trying to save an image captured with my android phone using phonegap, however 80% of the time I press the save button, after taking the picture, my app just dies...

I've seen that this is a common problem with phonegap + android. I've already tried lowering the  quality of the image, cleaning phone memory, erasing the cache directory of the app... Nothing so far, I still get this random behavior.

I've tried using imageData and imageURI, but still get the error.

Something to note is that everytime I rotate the phone, my app dies. Some times when I save an image, the screen automatically rotates, and that also kill the app.

Here is the code I have so far...

```
            // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
            //
            function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
                // Uncomment to view the image file URI
                // console.log(imageURI);

                $('#my_div') // this div belongs to my html markup (see bellow)
                    .empty()
                    .append(
                        $('<image>')
                            .attr('src', imageURI)
                            .attr('width', '100')
                            .attr('height', '100')
                            .css({
                                'background-color' : 'red',
                                 '-webkit-border-radius': '15px',
                                 '-moz-border-radius': '15px',
                                 'border-radius': '15px'
                            })
                );
            }

            // A button will call this function
            //
            function getPhoto(source) {
                // Retrieve image file location from specified source
                navigator.camera.getPicture(
                    function (imageUri) {
                        onPhotoURISuccess(imageUri, photo_div_id);   
                    }, 
                    onFail, {
                        quality: 30,
                        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                        sourceType: source
                    }
                );
            }

<div   id="my_div" class= "iconP">
   <input type="button"  name="photo_1" id="photo_1" onclick ="getPhoto()" value="photo 1"/>
</div>
```

Comment: If the answer you've got isn't helping, you should go check your LogCat and let us know what the error is.  If it's a Bitmap exceeds VM budget type error, that's one kind of problem, if it's a permissions issue, that's entirely different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add more to your mainfest than that, otherwise you'll run into this problem again.  Add the following: `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"`

Comment: That is exaclty the line phonegap suggest to add, however, my app won't event start if I add the complete string, thats why I had to remove the last three names. Either way, +1 for helping :)

Comment: I would still suggest you accept his answer as the correct one, as it helped you... and because nobody has answered in the last 3 years.