# App crashing after using correct orientation on samsung S2

Tags: android, cordova, android-camera, capture

Mobile:Samsung S2
PhoneGap:2.8.0
Replicate Again:After taking the image,clicked on save button then app is crashing.I tried with **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481632/android-app-dies-when-saving-image-captured-with-camera-and-rotating-phone)**
by changing mainfest.xml file still problem existing.

Here is my capture image code

```
$("#camera_photos").on('click',function(event)
    {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(imageCaptureSuccess, imageCaptureError, { quality: 30, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,targetWidth: 500,targetHeight: 500,saveToPhotoAlbum: true,correctOrientation: true }); 
    });
```

Please give me solution for this issue.

Comment: Please post logcat with the exception.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997050/android-crashing-after-camera-intent. It may be not easy to follow one of the suggested paths in PhoneGap, but I cannot suggest painless medicine.